# Autocomplete search result into Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]It might be novice question but I am trying to write a result of selected location from place autocomplete fragment (or from custom Autocomplete edittext) to firebase database. As per firebase's documentation java objects are automatically mapped.

But, I am getting an error that the object has to be serialized when I am trying write my object into firebase.

**Here is the Stacktrace:**

2020-03-07 02:24:47.149 8708-8708/com.smslunchdelivery.smslunchdelivery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smslunchdelivery.smslunchdelivery, PID: 8708
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:547)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:329)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:166)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:159)
        at com.smslunchdelivery.smslunchdelivery.FoodActivity.pushObjects(FoodActivity.java:237)
        at com.smslunchdelivery.smslunchdelivery.FoodActivity.access$100(FoodActivity.java:48)
        at com.smslunchdelivery.smslunchdelivery.FoodActivity$2.addToCardBtnClck(FoodActivity.java:175)
        at com.smslunchdelivery.smslunchdelivery.FoodAdapter$4.onClick(FoodAdapter.java:113)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

**My Object**

```
public class User {

    public Fragment placeAutoCompleteFragment;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }
    public User(Fragment placeAutoCompleteFragment, String email) {
        this.placeAutoCompleteFragment = placeAutoCompleteFragment;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
private void (String userId, String name, String email) {
    //Getting error message here.
    User user = new User(placeAutoCompleteFragment, email);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

**Firebase Documentation**

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

My question is: What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual error you get, and the specific line of code that causes it.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: DougStevenson and @Alex Mamo. Thank you guys. sure thing. will do it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Would you please share your insights. Thanks!

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273) - the same reasoning applies to error messages as well.  Also you need the stack trace which you did not include.

Comment: @RyanMentley Thank you Ryan. I will keep an eye on that. However, for your reference, I have copy and paste the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `User` class is not suitable for automatic serialization to Firestore.  The Fragment member is causing problems.  A class you want to serialize should only contain primitive types, lists and maps, and other objects that only contain the same types of data.  At the very minimum, remove the Fragment and find another way to deal with it outside of your POJO.

Comment: Thank you so much Doug! I am going to try something else. I have been trying to do it for couple of weeks. It's exciting.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase's documentation java objects are automatically mapped but the problem in here is that `Fragment` is an Android object, so it doesn't know how to serialize it.

Your data objects should be POJO (Plain Old Data Object) to be serialized and deserialized, there is no place for a Fragment in there or other android objects.

Comment: Classes don't need to implement Serializable in order to work with Firebase SDKs.